# Pass array to code behind from jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have to pass two dimensional array to the page method written at code behind of the web page in asp.net I have a variable `objList` as a two dimensional array. I used following code for achieving this with no success and page method is not called.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function BindTable(objList) {

    $.ajax(
    {
           url: "CompCommonQues.aspx/SaveData",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           type: "POST",
           data: { data: objList },
           success: function (data) {
           //Success code here
    },
    error: function () { }
    });
  }
```

**CODE BEHIND .CS File**

```
 [WebMethod]
public static string SaveData(string[,] data)
{
    string[,] mystring = data;
    return "saved";
}
```

There is method like JSON.stringify(objList) to pass the json array to code behind but couldn't implement this. A simple call wihtout array working for me like

```
data: "{ 'data':'this is string' }",
```

and in code behind

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveData(string data)
{
    string mystring = data;
    return "saved";
}
```

There is problem in passing `data`. Can you assist me how to pass it for arrays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the correct JSON notation in JavaScript

```
var objList = new Array();
objList.push(new Array("a","b"));
objList.push(new Array("a", "b"));
objList.push(new Array("a", "b"));

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "copyproduct.aspx/SaveDate",
       data: "{'data':'" + JSON.stringify(objList) + "'}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
       }
   });
```

In code behind, you can deserialize with JavaScriptSerializer (System.Web.Script.Serialization)

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string SaveDate(string data)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<string[]> mystring = json.Deserialize<List<string[]>>(data);
    return "saved";
}
```

I had to deserialize to a generic list of a string array because you can't deserialize to a string (check: http://forums.asp.net/t/1713640.aspx/1)

Comment: Web method is not hitting when i debug the code. What changes required in code behind function.

Comment: You are passing a string like: { data: [["a","b"],["a","b"],["a","b"]] }. So you need to change the parameter from string(,) to string and use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize to string(,). I will work out the example.

Comment: I have change my code as per your suggestion, Arrays are created but code behind method still not hitting.

Comment: Did you copied the code? Are you using Firebug? Can you see what message is displayed under "Net"> "XHR"? I have tested it in my project and it was working.

Comment: Error is `internal server error` Under the post section `{ data: [["123","1"],["153","2"],["123","1"],["123","1"],["153","2"],["123","1"],["123","1"],["153","2"],["123","1"]] }` and Message is `"Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array."`

Comment: I made a one-page website with working code: goo.gl/f5vHG Choose file > download and test it under Visual Studio.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27162/discussion-between-jurgenstillaert-and-eraj)

Comment: is there a way to reverse this by sending data from code behind to javascript variable as well

Comment: @vbNewbie You mean by pushing data to a client side variable?

Comment: @JurgenStillaert - yes but I am still trying to get the example above working with dojo included

Comment: @vbNewbie For pushing data to the client, you should consider using something like SignalR when using .NET.