# {"No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String[]'."} while deserailsing json data

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, deserialization

This is my controller

```
[NoCache]
    public ActionResult SaveAssociate(string data)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<string> mystring = json.Deserialize<List<string>>(data);
        return Content("Hai");
    }
```

Expression data
value :

```
[{"AssetName":"8888","AssetNumber":"8888","Classification":null,"ParentAsset":null,"SerialNumber":"8888","ParentCompany":"JPL Holdings","Barcode":null,"RFIDTags":null,"AssetId":"dfe2ae51-f153-4a67-bd3b-0114d8a40751","Notes":null,"Manufacturer":null,"DepartmentId":null,"Department":null,"SupplierId":null,"Supplier":null},{"AssetName":"552014","AssetNumber":"552014","Classification":null,"ParentAsset":"8888","SerialNumber":"552014","ParentCompany":"JPL Holdings","Barcode":null,"RFIDTags":null,"AssetId":"4109ba40-af78-486a-a40e-1d14a2d7b42f","Notes":null,"Manufacturer":null,"DepartmentId":null,"Department":null,"SupplierId":null,"Supplier":null},{"AssetName":"201","AssetNumber":"201","Classification":null,"ParentAsset":null,"SerialNumber":"2011","ParentCompany":"JPL Holdings","Barcode":null,"RFIDTags":null,"AssetId":"3e552280-16df-4c17-a4a5-1f61c4c96835","Notes":null,"Manufacturer":null,"DepartmentId":null,"Department":null,"SupplierId":null,"Supplier":null}]
```

At this line `List<string> mystring = json.Deserialize<List<string>>(data);`
am getting

```
{"No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String[]'."}
```

even i tried like this

```
 [Serializable]
public class GetUser
{
    public GetUserdata[] Data { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class GetUserdata
{
    public string AssetName { get; set; }
    public string AssetNumber { get; set; }
    public string Classification { get; set; }
    public string ParentAsset { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string ParentCompany { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string RFIDTags { get; set; }
    public string AssetId { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

controller

```
 public ActionResult SaveAssociate(string data)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        GetUser mystring = json.Deserialize<GetUser>(data);
        return Content("Hai");
    }
```

Am getting error
Type 'AssetTrackingSystem.Model.GetUser' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

Help me

Comment: I don't know ASP.net so I won't post any answers. I do question why you're saying `List` should be string when it is supposed to hold the return of a deserialization (which I assume would be an object or array or something)

Comment: Plz check my edit above

Comment: I've read the edit, my question still stands (with the caveat that I don't really know much about what I'm looking at). `Deserialize` shouldn't return a string, but your type casting and var names imply that you expect it to. The docs ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316(v=vs.110).aspx ) say it returns "The deserialized object."

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1713640.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699395/pass-array-to-code-behind-from-jquery-ajax this site shows it works..i followed this

Comment: @JAAulde Then how can i get that json data to a collection ..

Comment: I don't know--I was hoping my observation might be helpful to you, but I have no idea how accurate it may have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the above code, could you try:

```
 public ActionResult SaveAssociate(string data)
 {
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    GetUserdata[] myUsers = json.Deserialize<GetUserdata[]>(data);
    return Content("Hai");
  }
```

Because your Json is sent as an array of object not an object of array.
I hope it will help you.